# What does "stirth'" mean?

Tags: meaning

Or "stir th'" (where I saw is printed as "stirth'").
It's from a poem from Henry Wotton.

> This day Dame Nature seemed in love;
>   The lusty sap began to move;
>   Fresh juice did stir th’ embracing vines,
>   And birds had drawn their valentines;
>   The jealous trout that low did lie
>   Rose at the well-dissembled fly;
>   There stood my friend, with patient skill
>   Attending of his trembling quill.
>
> *On a Bank as I Sat A-fishing*
>   Sir Henry Wotton (1568–1639)
>
> http://www.bartleby.com/331/29.html

Answer (score 2):

The line is:

> Fresh juice did stir th’ embracing vines,

In this case, **th’** is simply a poetic abbreviation for **the**:

> Fresh juice did stir **the** embracing vines,

This avoids an extra syllable (and keeps the poem in iambic quadrimeter).